# WooCommerce Product Add-ons on Cart Page

Tags: wordpress, checkout, woocommerce, cart, add-on

I'm trying to insert, update and send data from the cart to the checkout page using the 'WooCommerce Product Add-ons' I've managed to get my custom add-on fields to display on the cart page but when clicking 'update' or 'checkout' none of the data inserted into the fields havn't been sent though. I have noticed the qty field data has been sent so I know its just not picking up the custom add-on fields. If anyone has any suggestins or have tried something similar I'd love to hear any solutions to this problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I need to add them to my product archive, and to the cart would be helpful as well.